Chisel Template Not Functioning Windows 11 - Cannot run program "which": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
After having cloned the template project for Chisel (https://github.com/chipsalliance/chisel-template) I tried running sbt test, and I got the following error in the file /src/test/scala/gcd/GCDSpec:
> Cannot run program "which": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "which": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1170)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1089)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:85)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:119)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$anonfun$runBuffered$1(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:205)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcI$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcI$sp.scala:17)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger$$anon$1.buffer(ProcessLogger.scala:103)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.runBuffered(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:205)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:146)
    at svsim.verilator.Backend$.initializeFromProcessEnvironment(Backend.scala:27)
    at chisel3.simulator.EphemeralSimulator$DefaultSimulator.<init>(EphemeralSimulator.scala:29)
    at chisel3.simulator.EphemeralSimulator$.makeSimulator(EphemeralSimulator.scala:44)
    at chisel3.simulator.EphemeralSimulator$.simulate(EphemeralSimulator.scala:25)
    at gcd.GCDSpec.$anonfun$new$1(GCDSpec.scala:29)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
    at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf$.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:104)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:22)
    at org.scalatest.Transformer.apply(Transformer.scala:20)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike$$anon$1.apply(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:437)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture(TestSuite.scala:196)
    at org.scalatest.TestSuite.withFixture$(TestSuite.scala:195)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec.withFixture(AnyFreeSpec.scala:1740)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.invokeWithFixture$1(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:435)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.$anonfun$runTest$1(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:447)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:306)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.runTest(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:447)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.runTest$(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:429)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec.runTest(AnyFreeSpec.scala:1740)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.$anonfun$runTests$1(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:506)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.$anonfun$runTestsInBranch$1(Engine.scala:413)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:401)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:396)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:475)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.runTests(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:506)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.runTests$(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:505)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec.runTests(AnyFreeSpec.scala:1740)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run(Suite.scala:1114)
    at org.scalatest.Suite.run$(Suite.scala:1096)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec.org$scalatest$freespec$AnyFreeSpecLike$$super$run(AnyFreeSpec.scala:1740)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.$anonfun$run$1(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:550)
    at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:535)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.run(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:550)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpecLike.run$(AnyFreeSpecLike.scala:549)
    at org.scalatest.freespec.AnyFreeSpec.run(AnyFreeSpec.scala:1740)
    at org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:47)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13(Runner.scala:1321)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$13$adapted(Runner.scala:1315)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:333)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1315)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24(Runner.scala:992)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$24$adapted(Runner.scala:970)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1481)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:970)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:798)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2or3(ScalaTestRunner.java:43)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:159)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1126)
    ... 59 more

Having looked into it, I believe the error stems from here:
>   def initializeFromProcessEnvironment() = {
    val output = mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[String]
    val exitCode = List("which", "verilator").!(ProcessLogger(output += _))
    if (exitCode != 0) {
      throw new Exception(s"verilator not found on the PATH!\n${output.mkString("\n")}")
    }
    val executablePath = output.head.trim
    new Backend(executablePath = executablePath)
  }
}

From the Chisel backend scala file.
This is my build.sbt file:
    > // See README.md for license details.
    
    ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.13.12"
    ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.0"
    ThisBuild / organization     := "com.github.brugerx"
    
    val chiselVersion = "6.2.0"
    
    lazy val root = (project in file("."))
      .settings(
        name := "FPGA_Course_SKYLAB",
        libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
          "org.chipsalliance" %% "chisel" % chiselVersion,
          "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.16" % "test",
        ),
        scalacOptions ++= Seq(
          "-language:reflectiveCalls",
          "-deprecation",
          "-feature",
          "-Xcheckinit",
          "-Ymacro-annotations",
        ),
        addCompilerPlugin("org.chipsalliance" % "chisel-plugin" % chiselVersion cross CrossVersion.full),
      )

I am using the following settings for my JDK:

Although I have tried with various JDK versions and language levels and still get the error.

Whereas the core of Chisel works well on Windows, the simulation-side relies on some Unixisms like the shell command which as seen in the error. We could fix that, but then you will immediately run into issues with Verilator (the Verilog simulator) which itself is full of Unixisms (e.g. it generates and runs a Make file).
Your best bet is to try out Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) which should provide the basic Linux APIs needed. Maybe Chisel can detect Windows without WSL and issue an error rather than crashing on the which invocation.

@JackKoenig Hello Jack, what exactly do you mean with try out WSL? I already have it installed as a run target, but how would I use it with Chisel tests in particular?

I am not super familiar with how it works (I don't use Windows) so I apologize for not having more precise recommendations, but I think you generally have to manually run things in the WSL environment. That screenshot looks like IntelliJ which has a doc mentioning you have to specifically use the JDK installed in WSL (as opposed to the default JDK on the system): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/how-to-use-wsl-development-environment-in-product.html#create_project_for_wsl. Please report back when you get things running!
